# bootstrap3 modal table not loading data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

Folks,
  I have been battling getting a modal tied to my table in bootstrap.

The following code does launch the modal, but does not display the values I am trying to pass.  I tried replicating the functionality here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yF45N/)

Right now, if i remove the JavaScript part from the bottom, the modal still loads... i really dont know how to get this working :(

What I would like:

1. Dynamically generated table (working now) via looping over pendingArray
2. Each table item you would click, would populate in the modal.

code:

```
.panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading Pending Requests
    .panel-body
        table.table-hover.table-condensed
            thead
                tr
                    th Email
                    th First Name
                    th Last Name
            tbody
                - each val in pendingArray
                    tr(data-toggle='modal', data-id="#{val.mid}",  data-target="#mvrDisplayModal")
                        td #{val.email}
                        td #{val.fName}
                        td #{val.lName}

#mvrDisplayModal.modal.fade.large
    .modal-dialog(style="width:70%")
        .modal-content
            .modal-header
                button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') &times;
                h2.modal-title fName lName

            #orderDetails.modal-body

            .modal-footer
                button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close


body
    script.
        $('#mvrDisplayModal').modal({
                keyboard: true,
                backdrop: "static",
                show: true,

            }).on('show', function(){
                var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('Email');
                $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'))
            });
        });
```

JS files loaded:

```
script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")
script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js")
script(src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js")
script(src='/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in JavaScript

```
script.
$('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');
    $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'))
});
```